# Subtract Business Days Using Date Dimension Calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Lots of comments suggested creating a date table in SQL Server for business day and holiday calculations - excellent idea!  I found a great how-to article to create such a set of tables in SQL Server - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/. I highly recommend this article if you need to do lots of date calculations.

From those tables, I created a view called USCalendar that calculates the end date, given a start date (03/01/21) and number of business days (180) - works perfectly!

```sql
select Top 1 TheDate as EndDate
from (
    select Top 180 TheDate from USCalendar
    Where TheDate>='03/01/2021'
    And IsWeekend=0 and IsHoliday=0
    Order By TheDate
) as BusinessDays
Order By TheDate DESC
```

My only challenge is coming up with a way to reverse it - how do I find the start date if I know the target end date and number of business days?

Comment: You could simply add a sequential number to your table that increments for every "work" day (repeated for non-work days). Then you simply find the row where this value is 100 away (in either direction) from that of your starting date. Credit to Joe Celko for that idea. Note that "business day" is not always the same as "work day" for a variety of reasons - natural disaster, forced closure, holiday, etc. Know your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't actually need all that if you want just the one date.**

You could do simply

```
select TheDate as EndDate
from USCalendar
Where TheDate >= '03/01/2021'
  And IsWeekend = 0 and IsHoliday = 0
Order By TheDate
OFFSET 179 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

To reverse this, we change it to `<=` and order in the other direction:

```
select TheDate as EndDate
from USCalendar
Where TheDate <= '03/01/2021'
  And IsWeekend = 0 and IsHoliday = 0
Order By TheDate DESC
OFFSET 179 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

I would advise you to **make this an inline Table-Valued Function**, so that you can put any date in. It basically becomes a parameterized view. It is inlined into the outer query, so it's very efficient:

```
CREATE /* OR ALTER */ FUNCTION dbo.GetBusinessEndDate
( @StartDate date, @numberOfDays int )
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN (
    select TheDate as EndDate
    from USCalendar
    Where TheDate >= @StartDate
      And IsWeekend = 0 and IsHoliday = 0
    Order By TheDate
    OFFSET @numberOfDays ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
);
```

You use this like any other table or view, you can also `CROSS APPLY` it.

I would advise to make a **separate** function for `StartDate`, do not attempt to combine it.

Comment: Awesome - that's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!